# Reject guest access in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, declarative-authorization

I want to completely lock down a Rails application, such that all routes which are not *explicitly authorized* for a particular user role are rejected (403).

I inherited this app, so my understanding of the framework is poor, but it currently seems like I have opposite: everything's open unless I explicitly close it.

I have an authorization_rules.rb file, and I've given the guest role *no* permissions, yet I can still access pages without being logged in. I think I can go in page by page and make sure a page requires authorization (filter_access_to  ?), but I might miss one. How can I just shut everything down, then open access only where I explicitly allow it?

This is using Rails 2.3.5.

Comment: do you have a require_user method in your application_controller? if you do, just add a before_filter :require_user, :except => [:login] to your application controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the app uses `before_filter` to restrict access, you can move the before filter in application controller and skip it for particular actions in individual controllers:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_filter :filter_access

#app/controllers/your_specific_controller.rb
skip_before_filter :filter_access, :only => [:action1_accessible_by_guest, :action2_accessible_by_guest]
```

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this, because the part about putting :filter_access in my application controller is what I missing. Once I did that, I was able to control access via config/authorization_rules.rb.